# Сделать Cython модуль из нескольких файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, cx-freeze, cython

Как заCythonить модуль в один файл?

У меня скомпиленные в один файл части видны снаружи, но внутри иерархия нарушается.

```
from .packet import Packet
```

выливается в

```
  File "libmodule/__init__.py", line 1, in init libmodule.__init__ (libmodule/__init__.c:1060)
...
ImportError: No module named 'libmodule.packet'
```

Вот чтоб взять

```
Extension("module", [
"module.py",
"libmodule/__init__.py",
"libmodule/worker.py",
"libmodule/decoders.py",
"libmodule/constants.py",
])
```

и закомпилить в один файл. Пока получается только в 5 файлов, но это не очень удобно.

В итоге нужно видеть функцию setup() из module.py, остальное не имеет значения. То есть `from libmodule.packet import Packet` не обязательно чтоб работало вне библиотеки.

Пример структуры, которой пытаюсь добиться https://github.com/eri-hellowords/cython-helloword/tree/v1 - не работает

Вот так работает, но структура мне не нравится
https://github.com/eri-hellowords/cython-helloword/tree/v2.0

Вариант затащить все файлы в один неймспейс через .pyx: stackoverflow.com/a/19698914/2101808

Comment: Хочу упаковать приложение в cx_freeze, а его основные компоненты собрать в cython. Проблема в том чтоб собрать компонент в один библиотечный файл.

Comment: Полный пример займет много места и не отразит сути вопроса почти никак. Соберу сейчас, добавлю.

Comment: @jfs добавил ссылку на пример кода.

Comment: 2 - минуту назад я написал вам не новый код с нуля?

Comment: 1 - хочу собрать 5 файлов в одну библиотеку, и плюс один файл который это запустит.

Comment: что вы хотите я так и не понял. *"собрать 5 файлов в одну библиотеку"* -- это называется Питон-пакет (include использовать как в С совершенно не нужно, посмотрите как `asyncio/__init__.py` выглядит). *"плюс один файл который это запустит"* -- если вы имеете ввиду что вместо инсталляции, просто всё в один файл запаковать, то это использование cx-freeze объясняет. Зачем Cython не ясно.

Comment: cython чтоб выделить питоновский модуль в модуль программы.
почти как плагин. в asyncio/__init__.py ничего нового не увидел - пачка импортов. проблема в том что cython не следует импортам при компиляции, а просто сшивает файлы если ему указать несколько

Comment: *"выделить питоновский модуль в модуль программы"* —я не понимаю что это значит. Вы утилиту командной строки как один исполняемый файл хотите распространять (со встроенным питон-интерпретатором)? (это я могу понять: ничего ставить не надо, дал один файл, который запускать можно людям, которые слово Питон могут и не знать). Или вы хотите библиотеку для Питон-программистов создать (и хотите, чтобы она снаружи как один модуль выглядела, даже если реализация по нескольким модулям разбросана)? В этом случае я ваши манипуляции с cython, cx-freeze не понимаю (достаточно, чтобы `pip install` работал).

Comment: почти. как несколько файлов. запускалка и рабочие процессы. запускалка в exe, рабочие процессы в dll. почти как плагинами расширяемое приложение. для разработчиков пока нет, для людей которые способны скопировать и 2 раза щелкнуть и перейти в админку по вэб - да, это для них.

Comment: в библиотеках службы, которые работают в фоне. отделить от запускалки надо потому что запускаться оно может по-разному: как сервис виндовс, как служба системд, как служба к старому доброму иниту, как задача в терминале и тд. и службы то разные в конечном проекте, разный набор в зависимости от нужд пользователя. просто 3 раза компилирую всё и делаю 12 сборок из этого...

Comment: я не услышал ничего, что указало бы *что конкретно и зачем* требует cython в вашем проекте (я так понял--весь код у вас чистый Питон). Я правда не понимаю выражения "рабочие процессы в dll" (это как "дома в кирпиче" звучит), "в библиотеках службы" (как код и запущенный процесс связаны--какую роль ваш проект здесь играет). То что я услышал говорит, что cx-freeze вас не спасёт (по крайней мере непродуктивно всё в один `setup.py` пытаться уместить--требования широкие). И пользователям может легче с полноценным установщиком, который службы зарегистрирует, запустит, положит утилиты в %PATH% итд.

Comment: с установщиком теряем портабельность и обновлять неудобно